# Yii2: how to use rtrim in foreach loop?

Tags: php, yii2

I'm getting images from database which holds path of the images each path is separated by ';' i need to ignore the last ';' because when it is displaying the images from db its getting last ';' and showing broken thumbnail in view

```
<?php
foreach (explode(';', $row['images']) rtrim($row['images'],';') as $key_img => $value_img)
{
echo Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/'.$value_img,[
' height'=> 500,
'width'=> 500,
]);
}
?>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Yii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want explode the result of rtrim   you shold do this way

```
foreach (explode(';',  rtrim($row['images'],';')) as $key_img => $value_img)
```

or you could need  a substr

```
yourString =  substr($row['images'],strlen($row['images'])- 1);
```

Comment: I need to rtrim only last ';'  like path1;path2;path3; should remove only last ';'

Comment: Then you don't need the explode? show a start $row image sample too